# EOF caught while checking if connected while using phpmailer

Tags: smtp, phpmailer

I've some problem trying to use `phpmailer` on my localhost.

I've been trying for at least 2 hours to connect my `ionos` 1&1 SMTP server using `phpmailer`.

```
<<?php 
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);         //Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.ionos.fr';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'mymail@mymail.fr';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'mypassword';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to
//Recipients
$mail->setFrom('anyrecipient@test.fr', 'Test');
$mail->addAddress('realadress@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient

//Content
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';



 $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo '<br>' . 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
 ?>
```

In fact, here is the error logs:

> <2019-01-02 09:02:04 Connection: opening to smtp.ionos.fr:465,
>   timeout=300, options=array() 2019-01-02 09:02:04 Connection: opened
>   2019-01-02 09:02:15 SMTP INBOUND: "" 2019-01-02 09:02:15 SERVER ->
>   CLIENT:  2019-01-02 09:02:15 SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if
>   connected 2019-01-02 09:02:15 Connection: closed SMTP Error: Could not
>   connect to SMTP host. SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
>
> Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect
>   to SMTP host.

Any advise/clue?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried changing the port? From this page https://www.ionos.co.uk/help/email-office/general-topics/settings-for-your-email-programs-imap-pop3/, the TLS is on port 587 but you've set 465 which is SSL

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs & examples. You’re using `SMTPSecure = 'tls'` With `Port = 465`. It’s very well documented that that combination will not work. Either change to `ssl` or port 587, but not both.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works fine with SMTPSecure = 'tls' and port 587.
Still, I don't understand why, on 1&1 website, they show the following configuration:
Server: smtp.ionos.fr
Port: 465

I'm a bit disappointed with them for that...

Thanks a lot Synchro :)

Comment: So it works fine with PORT 587 and tls when running my script on localhost. Hence, when I tried on IONOS 1&1 server, I got the SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server. I contacted the IONOS support and they told me that I can NOT use SMTP because I was on a mutualized server. In fact, I have suscribed to theire so call  "basic offer", wich does not come with a DEDICATED server. I'm screwed, or I have to pay much more for a dedicated server :(

Comment: As I suspected... but you can get a full dedicated server from Scaleway or Hetzner for €3/month, so it’s not exactly expensive.

Comment: Thanks Synchro, i'm gonna check that